# How would I make text like this in illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text

I am designing a poster for fun, and I was wondering how to go about creating this text effect. I am really new at graphic design so any answer with as much detail would be really appreciated

[image: Text Example]

Comment: 1 thin line 1 thicker line + blend tool and then just punch a hole on the letters using the lines

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It's same as @Joonas said**

just uploading it with little more details

Step 1 - draw two straight lines; but keep in mind that second line should be more thicker than 1st line as you can see in below image.

Step 2 - Go to `Object-Blend-Blend Options` => then choose mode to `specific Steps` and set steps to `5`;

Step 3 - Select both lines and then go to `Object-Blend-Make` or <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+B</kbd>

Step 4 - now you should have pattern like you want after that you can always expand objects by `Object-Expand` and furthermore can clip it too; Hope it helps :)

[image]